# Freemarker cant find templates

Tags: freemarker

I have a template file which contains the following

```
{ MERGEFIELD [#include 'some.txt' parse=false] \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

some.txt resides in the same directory as the template file:
both of them are in src/main/java/resources/template

I get this exception all the time, no matter how I provide the path*.

```
freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for name "fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@37fcf94c!word/some.txt
```

*I have tried these:

```
      { MERGEFIELD [#include 'some.txt' parse=false] \* MERGEFORMAT }
      { MERGEFIELD [#include './some.txt' parse=false] \* MERGEFORMAT }
      { MERGEFIELD [#include '/absolutepath/some.txt' parse=false] \* MERGEFORMAT }
      { MERGEFIELD [#include '*/some.txt' parse=false] \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

I am totally clueless, because my file is in the same directory as the template file and the [official documentation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_include.html) states:

> The path parameter can be a relative path like "foo.ftl" and
>   "../foo.ftl", or an absolute like "/foo.ftl". Relative paths are
>   relative to the directory of the template that contains the import
>   directive.

Comment: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_templateloading.html You'll need to load them from the classpath. It's trying to load files, which are different than file *resources*.

Comment: Question is, what `TampleLoader` does you application use, and if the name given to the template you are in is meaningful to it. (As far as I remember FreeMarker prints the `TemplateLoader` class name for a while... maybe try a newer version to see that.)